# Android - Positioning layout items relative to top of sliding drawer handle

Tags: android, layout, slidingdrawer, sliding

I would like to position an element of an activity's layout relative to the top of a sliding drawer handle in its closed state.  The standard `Layout above` relative layout attribute obviously doesn't work given the floating nature of sliding drawer.

It seems to me that the only (non-programmatic) alternative is to bottom-align and used fixed margins or bottom padding to ensure the element sits above the closed sliding drawer handle.  This approach is pretty crude and I'm hoping to avoid this because I would like the sliding drawer handle height to be dependent on its content (which is dynamic).

Any suggestions to help achieve a more fluid layout?

Answer (score 1):

You can control the height of the sliding drawer if you want to and I think that is the case with this question. The sliding drawer is just taking some space of the screen and other content should be above it

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a LinearLayout (Vertical), and set its position to  bottom-align

Comment: No, I don't believe you can.  When using a sliding drawer widget the underlying layout containing the sliding drawer must be a relative or frame layout to allow the sliding drawer to float over the other elements.

Comment: And in case I misunderstood what you were suggesting it is perhaps worth pointing out that a sliding drawer widget appears to naturally fill its parent layout so bottom-or-top-aligning any component with the sliding drawer is equivalent to bottom-or-top-aligning with the parent layout.